# ZXing can not read this QRCode

Tags: c#, zxing, zxing.net

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ZXing;

namespace SeparatorPageSplit.framework
{
    class QRCodeScanner
    {
        BarcodeReader reader;
        public QRCodeScanner()
        {
            try
            {
                this.reader = new BarcodeReader { AutoRotate = true, TryInverted = true };
                this.reader = new BarcodeReader();
                this.reader.Options.PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
                this.reader.Options.PossibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
                // this.reader.Options.TryHarder = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Program.WriteToLogFile(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        public Boolean IsQRCodeFound(string ImagePath)
        {
            string decoded = "";
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(ImagePath);
            try
            {
                Result result = this.reader.Decode(bitmap);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    decoded = result.ToString().Trim();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Program.WriteToLogFile(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                bitmap.Dispose();
            }

            if (decoded == "CCA001")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I tried to read the following image:

[image]

This code works fine if I scan in color or grayscale.  It does not work when I scan in black and white.

Is there some setting in ZXing that will allow this to scan?

Is there a simple way to scrub the small dots?

[EDIT] We are using ZXing.Net v0.16.5 installed from Nuget in Visual Studio.  Nuget shows that at the latest version available.

Comment: Make sure you are using latest version : https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/issues/207

Comment: zxing doesn't work very well with b&w images. Most of the time the scanners adding some weird black pixel at the edges of the codes. The internal heuristic has trouble with them. If possible use grayscale images. If that is not possible, convert the image from b&w to grayscale and add a gaussian blur filter before decoding.

Comment: @Michael Is there an alternative QRCode reader that can handle B/W images?

Comment: There are a number of other barcode scanning libraries. Not sure if the can handle it, but I think so. And most of them are not free of charge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code that was able to read color, black/white, and grey scale:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ZXing;

namespace SeparatorPageSplit.framework
{
    class QRCodeScanner
    {
        //BarcodeReader reader;
        QRCodeDecoderLibrary.QRDecoder QRCodeDecoder;

        public QRCodeScanner()
        {
            try
            {
                QRCodeDecoder = new QRCodeDecoderLibrary.QRDecoder();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Program.WriteToLogFile(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        public Boolean IsQRCodeFound(string ImagePath)
        {
            string decoded = "";
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(ImagePath);
            try
            {
                byte[][] DataByteArray = QRCodeDecoder.ImageDecoder(bitmap);
                decoded = QRCodeResult(DataByteArray);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Program.WriteToLogFile(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                bitmap.Dispose();
            }

            if (decoded == "CCA001")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Format result for display
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="DataByteArray"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static string QRCodeResult(byte[][] DataByteArray)
        {
            // no QR code
            if (DataByteArray == null) return string.Empty;

            // image has one QR code
            if (DataByteArray.Length == 1) return ForDisplay(QRCodeDecoderLibrary.QRDecoder.ByteArrayToStr(DataByteArray[0]));

            // image has more than one QR code
            StringBuilder Str = new StringBuilder();
            for (int Index = 0; Index < DataByteArray.Length; Index++)
            {
                if (Index != 0) Str.Append("\r\n");
                Str.AppendFormat("QR Code {0}\r\n", Index + 1);
                Str.Append(ForDisplay(QRCodeDecoderLibrary.QRDecoder.ByteArrayToStr(DataByteArray[Index])));
            }
            return Str.ToString();
        }

        private static string ForDisplay(string Result)
        {
            int Index;
            for (Index = 0; Index < Result.Length && (Result[Index] >= ' ' && Result[Index] <= '~' || Result[Index] >= 160); Index++) ;
            if (Index == Result.Length) return Result;

            StringBuilder Display = new StringBuilder(Result.Substring(0, Index));
            for (; Index < Result.Length; Index++)
            {
                char OneChar = Result[Index];
                if (OneChar >= ' ' && OneChar <= '~' || OneChar >= 160)
                {
                    Display.Append(OneChar);
                    continue;
                }

                if (OneChar == '\r')
                {
                    Display.Append("\r\n");
                    if (Index + 1 < Result.Length && Result[Index + 1] == '\n') Index++;
                    continue;
                }

                if (OneChar == '\n')
                {
                    Display.Append("\r\n");
                    continue;
                }

                Display.Append('¿');
            }
            return Display.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```